# Licensing Activation Software

Tags: c#, obfuscation

I wrote a software product and want to sell it online. The same code source offers all the features, but I only want to activate "Standard" and "Pro" features based on what the customer purchases.

Ideally, the product works with the purchasing workflow, like this:

- Customer purchases the "Standard" or "Pro" SKU on my website.
- Customer receives an email with the license key.
- When the customer opens my product, it knows from the license key
  what features (Standard or Pro, for example) the customer purchased
  and activates.
- The customer upgrades on my website and they get a new key via email.
- Customer enters a new serial number and go from, say, Standard to
  Pro.

Since I am using Wordpress, I tried the WooCommerce software add-on but it just generates a serial number. It does not provide the ability to define a unique code that allows me to determine what features the customer is receiving.

Can you recommend a good solution? I am new at this and I have a small budget (

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It had been more helpful if you had given us some more details like how many licenses are you planning to sell. I can recommend [Portable.Licensing (GitHub)](https://github.com/dnauck/Portable.Licensing). It handles both the hassles of your web-based end and software front end.

> Portable.Licensing is a cross platform software licensing framework
>   which allows you to implement licensing into your application or
>   library. It provides you all tools to create and validate licenses for
>   your software.
>
> Portable.Licensing is using the latest military strength,
>   state-of-the-art cryptographic algorithm to ensure that your software
>   and thus your intellectual property is protected.
>
> It is targeting the Portable Class Library and thus runs on nearly
>   every .NET/Mono profile including Silverlight, Windows Phone, Windows
>   Store App, Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.Mac and XBox 360. Use
>   it for your Desktop- (WinForms, WPF, etc.), Console-, Service-, Web-
>   (ASP.NET, MVC, etc.), Mobile (Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android) or even
>   LightSwitch applications.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the recommendation and I will take a look. FYI, I did not state in my question what language I am using, but I do tag the post as C#.